# run error in eclipse when trying to run cucumber file

Tags: java, cucumber

This Error is appears when i  trying to run junit test on eclipse using cucumber

```
ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cucumber/runtime/snippets/SummaryPrinter
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cucumber.runtime.snippets.SummaryPrinter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 7 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error while upgrading the Cucumber version in my Maven based project.

Turn out that I updated `<artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>` version from 1.1.5 to 1.2.4, but I didn't update `<artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>` - it was still on 1.1.5.

On the moment I updated both to the same version, this error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Update cucumber-core,cucumber-java and cucumber-junit to the same version ( i have used 1.1.5 version ).The issue is resolved for me.